# Jquerymobile Json listview

Tags: json, html, jquery, mobile

I use jquerymobile and now i want to put li inside to a ul listview with json.

I have to follow code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("url",function(data) {
                $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){

                $('#output').children('ul').append('<li><a href="#">'+data.title+'</a></li>');

                });
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">   
        <div id="output">
               <ul data-role="listview">

                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

It works but not inside the .

Does anyone now how i can fix this?

Kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of child/children may be throwing it off a bit, give this a try, and see if that makes a difference.

```
$('#output ul').append(..........);
```

Since you are appending these list items to a list after the DOM is loaded, and are using jQueryMobile you will have to add an additional item to the chain of functions for the element. like so:

```
$('#output ul').append(..........).trigger('create');
```

Create is a jquery mobile event. that is fired off when the DOM is initially loaded, styling all elements that are in the DOM when its loaded. However by adding new ones they won't have the styling as jquerymobile doesn't rely on css through conventional stylesheet relations. It uses stylesheets for the styling but the styling gets applied according to the container types example

`data-role="header"` gets styled after the dom is loaded, so even if you styled the specific element using conventional methods with CSS jquery mobile will override it after the DOM is ready

Comment: It look like it's work, but it don't the style but it don't get the style from the listview from jwuerymobile..

Comment: jquerymobile has a "recreate" method or build or something to that extent I cant remember what it is exactly. But when you add elements to the DOM after its loaded you have to run this method on them to get them to style.

Comment: Im not sure if this is correct, but apply the logic mentioned above in my answer and "chain" `.page()` to the end of it. I think again not 100% sure that will apply the styles you have setup to the newly added elements, you may have to think of a little different means of applying it seeing as its going through a loop and you only wanna do it once, so maybe outside after the loop instead of append put page, while leaving inside the loop append.

Comment: I think you mean: $('#output ul').listview('refresh');    i add this but it is not working.

Comment: I was wrong with the `.page()` admittedly, I went out and looked through one of my old projects that used jquerymobile as the backing lib with jquery. to refresh the elements appended to the DOM after the DOM is loaded you would chain `.trigger('create');` to the end of the Ill update my example above

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("url",function(data) {

                $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){

                $('#output ul').append('<li></li>');

                });
                $('#output ul').listview('refresh');
            }
        );      
    });             
});

</script>
```